# Why is a FrameLayout used for fragments?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-framelayout

Wherever I look, `FrameLayout` seems to be used as the `FragmentContainer`.
Why is `FrameLayout` always seen with `Fragments`?

Comment: comment from 2020: You should use FragmentContainerView now as it contains fixes for exiting fragments.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can basically use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` it will still work,but the answer of your question is in `FrameLayout`'s documentation :

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
>   attribute.

You can read more about `FrameLayout` here : [FrameLayout/Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Answer (score 22):

Main purpose of frame layout is to block the area required to fit the largest child view. If you use a Frame Layout as Fragment Container you can ensure that you always have the space available to accommodate the largest fragment layout.

In some cases you may need to have more than 1 fragment on screen simultaneously in that case you should prefer Relative or Linear Layout.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is based on user requirements and customization needed.

It is not necessary to use FrameLayout at all.

For example in below code there is no layout taken , and fragment itself only contains single imageview .

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    String TAG="MyFragment";
    Context c;
    MyFragment(Context con){
    c=con;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ImageView v=new ImageView(c);
            //other imageview stuff

        return v;
    }
    @Overrides
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onClcik");

    }
}
```